# Remove some "duplicates" from a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django QuerySet containing several results for a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    date_seen = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now the QuerySet is limited over time and contains duplicate results:

```
MyModel.date_seen   - MyModel.value
2016-03-01 10:00:00 - 124
2016-03-01 11:00:00 - 124
2016-03-01 12:00:00 - 99
2016-03-01 13:00:00 - 99
2016-03-01 14:00:00 - 99
2016-03-01 15:00:00 - 103
2016-03-01 16:00:00 - 103
2016-03-01 17:00:00 - 176
2016-03-01 18:00:00 - 12
2016-03-01 19:00:00 - 12
```

Now what I want to have is a QuerySet only containing the results where the value has changed, so the result would be the following:

```
MyModel.date_seen   - MyModel.value
2016-03-01 10:00:00 - 124
2016-03-01 12:00:00 - 99
2016-03-01 15:00:00 - 103
2016-03-01 17:00:00 - 176
2016-03-01 18:00:00 - 12
```

The list is just an example and the result count is significantly higher (about 1000 results) so I need a performant solution ;-) Is this even possible? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Btw. I use postgresql underneath as database.

Comment: Have you tried with `distinct()`? -> `qs.distinct('value')` where `qs` is your queryset

Comment: Let's consider this set of values (ordered by time): `12, 12, 90, 90, 90, 12`. Which result would be correct: a) `12, 90` or b) `12, 90, 12`? i.e. if a value comes up again but is separated by other values is it a duplicate or not?

Comment: @Gocht I tried, but that gave me a `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` exception.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer the correct result would be `12,90,12`, if a value comes up after another value it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Then, perform an order by and a distinct -> `qs.order_by('value').distinct()`

Comment: @Gocht Ah thanks, that gives a result, but with the "duplicates" as I described contained.

Comment: On distinct specify the fields that should be distinct -> `...disctinct('value')`

Comment: @Gocht For my example your solution will result in `12, 90` instead of `12, 90, 12`. The result will also by ordered by values instead of date, which may or may not be a problem. Doing the thing @dArignac wants is way more complicated and can't be accomplished with `disctinct` alone.

Comment: would it be okay to not have a QuerySet anymore but a list as the result?

Comment: @niklas It would be ok. I'd prefer a solution via database but if that does not work, we'll have to do it in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a one query solution that only works on POSTGRESQL, based on [this beautiful post](http://fle.github.io/detect-value-changes-between-successive-lines-with-postgresql.html), where they explain how to make use of postgres [`lead`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) function that can be used to evaluate values of arbitrary rows before the current row. Just make sure to replace clubs_mymodel with [yourappname]_mymodel in the query below and you should be ready to go!

**Output:**

```
for m in MyModel.objects.all():
   print m

2016-03-21 10:00:00+00:00 - 124.0
2016-03-21 11:00:00+00:00 - 124.0
2016-03-21 12:00:00+00:00 - 99.0
2016-03-21 13:00:00+00:00 - 99.0
2016-03-21 14:00:00+00:00 - 99.0
2016-03-21 16:00:00+00:00 - 103.0
2016-03-21 15:00:00+00:00 - 103.0
2016-03-21 17:00:00+00:00 - 176.0
2016-03-21 18:00:00+00:00 - 12.0
2016-03-21 19:00:00+00:00 - 12.0
2016-03-21 20:00:00+00:00 - 90.0
2016-03-21 21:00:00+00:00 - 12.0

q = MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT m1.id, m1.value, m1.date_seen \
    FROM (SELECT m2.id, m2.value, m2.date_seen, lead(m2.value) \
        OVER (ORDER BY m2.date_seen DESC) as prev_value \
        FROM clubs_mymodel m2 ORDER BY m2.date_seen) as m1 \
    WHERE m1.value IS DISTINCT FROM m1.prev_value \
    ORDER BY m1.date_seen ASC')

for m in q:
   print m

2016-03-21 10:00:00+00:00 - 124.0
2016-03-21 12:00:00+00:00 - 99.0
2016-03-21 15:00:00+00:00 - 103.0
2016-03-21 17:00:00+00:00 - 176.0
2016-03-21 18:00:00+00:00 - 12.0
2016-03-21 20:00:00+00:00 - 90.0
2016-03-21 21:00:00+00:00 - 12.0
```

Comment: This is 100% correct. I was literally 5 seconds away for posting my answer that was almost word for word the same as this one, including code and references ;) I don't think a better solution exists.

Comment: Wow, this is it, thanks so much! I knew there had to be something. I read the article and adjusted it to the additional contraints I have (which I did not mention on purpose) and it worked. Great!